Are $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonians dual to Hermitian Hamiltonians?
I was reading this review paper by Bender, in particular section VI where they show that, despite $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonians not being hermitian, they can have a  real spectra. They go on to show that one can cook a proper inner product by defining an operator $\mathcal{C}$ such that the evolution is unitary.
My question is very simple:

Is it always possible to find a Hermitian Hamiltonian equivalent to any given $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonian whose evolution is unitary?

By dual here I mean that it reproduces the same physics, i.e. it can reproduce any observables at any time $t$ identically to the $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonian.
My motivation is simple: For any unitary matrix $U$ of finite size, $U$ can be written as $U = e^{iH}$, where $H$ is a Hermitian matrix. Now, I don't know if this is sufficient to show the existence of this equivalence.
I mean, if this is true, I can't help the feeling that this $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonians research business is a bit misleading in making the community believe there is more than Hermitian $H$'s. So what am I missing?

Suggestion to the post (v2): Replace the word dual with the word equivalent.

@Qmechanic happy to change it. Is there a reason why dual is not the correct term here? (And why equivalent is?)

@FriendlyLagrangian dual has a mathematical meaning different from the use we give to it in spoken languages. Dual in a math context refers to (usually) an involutive functor, i.e. duality is a 1-1 correspondence between different mathematical objects. Two operators are both operators, so "dual" is not the right term. An example of duality are vectors and 1-forms

I don't think I know enough about this subject to answer the question, but I think its a big deal (in normal quantum mechanics) that the inner product which we use when computing Born-rule probabilities is the same inner product that self-adjoint Hamiltonians are self-adjoint with respect to. You can cook up an inner product with respect to which these $\mathcal{PT}$ Hamiltonians are Hermitian but the inner product we use for the Born rule doesn't change so the physics will be noticeably different.

A separate comment about your last sentence. I think its reasonable to consider non Hermitian Hamiltonians in the context of open quantum systems. You can come up with examples where the global time evolution is unitary, but the local evolution of whatever subsystem you're looking at isn't. Of course there are other ways to model open quantum systems (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindbladian), but maybe for some examples these non-Hermitian Hamiltonians are a reasonable description.

@ors I don't quite agree with your point. Almost any closed (unitary) system will have those properties. Namely, if you study a closed (unitary) many-body system, then your local physics are likely going to be that of an open system, i.e. when you partial trace into it. In fact, you will typically find that local subsystems of closed (unitary) many-body systems are thermal (see for instance ETH https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenstate_thermalization_hypothesis) although that is not always the case (see for instance MBL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-body_localization).

As far as I understand, whether or not a system is locally thermal depends on certain properties of the entire closed system Hamiltonian. For instance, you will commonly see locality and randomness involved in making Hamiltonians violate ETH. All in all, this comes down to the same original question I had: if an evolution is unitary, Why should we care if it accepts or not a non-hermitian Hamiltonian given there seems to be always a Hermitian description of the physics?

@FriendlyLagrangian Lets say the system you're trying to describe is a photon travelling through a fibre-optic cable. You can (of course) get a unitary description of the entire coupled photon+cable system, and it will be described by a Hermitian Hamiltonian. However this Hamiltonian is probably going to be rather complicated and impractical, since the fibre-optic is a big complicated system. If you can get some description of just the effective evolution of the photon (which is what you care about) then that will simplify things significantly.

@ors I completely agree with you. It might very well indeed be a very useful mathematical tool under the right circumstances worth learning more about. I guess my question is simply different: is there (new) physics out there only describable by $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonians outside of the range of hermitian Hamiltonians?

@FriendlyLagrangian I think within the realm of "normal quantum mechanics" the answer to that question is pretty clearly no (e.g. by Wigner's theorem).  If you go slightly beyond that you might find examples. Once place to look that comes to mind is people who think about objective collapse models (where wavefunction collapse is a physical non-unitary process). I think continuous spontaneous localization models can be described like this, but I've never really been interested in those so I can't comment further.

The paper is quite long and technical. It is written without any care for any mathematical rigor, just in the spirit of theoretical physics (in particular there is no distinction between Hermitian, symmetric, and selfadjoint operators which is fundamental to assure the validity of the spectral theorem). However it is evidently physically interesting!
As far as I understand, the strategy is to define a bijective operator, not unitary, from the original Hilbert space ${\cal H}$ to another Hilbert space ${\cal H}'$, of the form
$$S:= e^{-Q/2} : {\cal H} \to {\cal H}'\:.$$
The new Hamiltonian operator (Eq. (6.34))
$$h := S H S^{-1}$$
is argued to be Hermitian in ${\cal H}'$, whereas the original on $H$ in ${\cal H}$ is not (but is ${\cal PT}$-symmetric). The transformation $a \to S aS^{-1}$ is often called an equivalence transformation.
I do not know (presumably the paper defines it) what is the scalar product in ${\cal H}'$, but $V$ is not unitary, i.e., it does not preserve the scalar product:
$$\langle S\psi|S\phi \rangle_{{\cal H}'}\neq \langle \psi|\phi \rangle_{{\cal H}}\quad in\: general,$$
(otherwise also $h$ would be Hermitian and we do know that it is false!).
Physically speaking, immediate drawbacks (presumably this is what you are missing) of this procedure are that
(a) other Hermitian operators in ${\cal H}$ turns out to be non-Hermitian in ${\cal H}'$ under the equivalence transformation induced by $S$;
(b) a direct interpretation of $|\langle \chi|\rho\rangle_{{\cal H}'}|^2$ as transition probability is disputable.
I think that all that is physically acceptable ant it is related to the fact that the system is considered an open system.
In any cases, I strongly expect that the paper examines these issues in details, since they pop out immediately and C. M. Bender is a world authority on the subject of the work.
ADDENDUM. I comment also about the claim (somewhere present in the paper) that the evolution is unitary in spite of $H$ being non-Hermitian.
I do not understand well this claim, however, let us assume that it means that $\mathbb{R}\ni t \mapsto U_t := e^{-itH}$ is a strongly continuous one-parameter group of  unitary operators in the Hilbert space ${\cal H}$.
If it is the case, the Stone theorem implies that there is a (unique) selfadjoint operator $H' :D(H) \to {\cal H}$ such that $e^{-itH'} = U_t$ for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Here $D(H)$ is exactly the dense subspace of vectors $\psi \in {\cal H}$ such that, the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} U_t \psi$$
exists. Also, this derivative just defines $-iH'\psi$.
Putting all together (if $H'$ is defined on domain identical to the one of $H$ or larger) we conclude that $H$ is Hermitian as $H'$ is!
Indeed,
$$H'\psi = i\frac{d}{dt} U_t \psi = i \frac{d}{dt} e^{-itH}\psi = H\psi\:.$$
We know that it is not the case a priori. So, I cannot see an evident way to interpret the claim that  the evolution generated by $H$ is unitary.

I'm not sure I agree? They mention several times the evolution is unitary (provided the spectrum is real). For instance in the intro or in section C: "In Sec. VI we show that if the eigenspectrum of a $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonian $H$ is entirely real, then $H$ defines a unitary theory of quantum mechanics."
This brings me back to my original question:
Is it always possible to find a Hermitian Hamiltonian equivalent to any given $\mathcal{PT}$-symmetric Hamiltonian whose evolution is unitary?

I did not notice this remark, thanks. I have had just a quick look at the paper. If they say this, and if the evolution is strongly continuous in addition to unitary, then there is a selfadjoint generator of the time evolution as a trivial consequence of the Stone theorem. Is there a precise spot where they explicitly describe that unitary evolution "generated" by the non -Hermitian Hamiltonian?  (Notice that $e^{-ith}$ is unitary. Maybe they are saying that this is the unitary evolution).

@FriendlyLagrangian I believe that the statements there refer to a formal or analogue mathematical system that looks like unitary quantum mechanics in every mathematical sense of the word. However, the formal scalar product or the formal Hermitian operators in the new space $\mathcal{H}'$ do not correspond to true physical observables and measurements that you perform on the system in the real world as they would in true quantum mechanics.

@ValterMoretti Indeed, your addendum is exactly my concern: I am not sure what their claim means. To me it feels as if the assumption of a strongly continuous one-parameter group of unitary operators has to hold. Otherwise, they would be considering exclusively "pathological" situations. I say "exclusively" because otherwise, as you say, there exists a Hermitian description of the system and then what would be their point? I think I am missing the point of these theories completely or there is some overselling...

I think that the authors' claim is that the evolution is unitary if we change the scalar product. I do not know if they use the scalar product  they associate to the transform induced by $Q$ in that part of their paper. Perhaps they use what they call "CPT scalar product" (defined somewhere there around). For me, it is very difficult to read that paper in view of the way it is written.
